# Bash addition by the first column, if data in second column is the same

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a list with delimiters `|`

```
40|192.168.1.2|user4
42|192.168.1.25|user2
58|192.168.1.55|user3
118|192.168.1.3|user11
67|192.168.1.25|user2
```

As you can see, I have the same ip in the field `42|192.168.1.25|user2` and in the field `67|192.168.1.25|user2`. How can I append these lines between them ? Can you give me a solution using `awk`. Can you give me some examples ?

I need in a result something like this:

```
40|192.168.1.2|user4
58|192.168.1.55|user3
109|192.168.1.25|user2
118|192.168.1.3|user11
```

How you can see, we have counted the numbers from first column.

Comment: what do you want to do if the ip addresses are the same, but the user id is different, eg: `42|192.168.1.25|user1` and `36|192.168.1.25|user9`

Comment: yes, this is a question. that i should append only by ip

Comment: given the 2 sample rows I provided in my previous comment ... what would you expect the output to be?  display `user1` or display `user9`?

Comment: display first user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need output in same order in which Input_file is there then following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk -F"|" '!c[$2,$3]++{val++;v[val]=$2$3} {a[$2,$3]+=$1;b[$2,$3]=$2 FS $3;} END{for(j=1;j<=val;j++){print a[v[j]] FS b[v[j]]}}' SUBSEP=""   Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -F"|" '        ##Making field separator as pipe(|) here for all the lines for Input_file.
!c[$2,$3]++{       ##Checking if array C whose index is $2,$3 is having its first occurrence in array c then do following.
  val++;           ##incrementing variable val value with 1 each time cursor comes here.
  v[val]=$2$3      ##creating an array named v whose index is val and value is $2$3(second field 3rd field).
}                  ##Closing c array block here now.
{
  a[$2,$3]+=$1;    ##creating an array named a whose index is $2 $3 and incrementing its value with 1st field value and add in its same index values to get SUM.
  b[$2,$3]=$2 FS $3;##create array b with index of $2$3 and setting its value to $2 FS $3, where FS is field separator.
}                  ##closing this block here.
END{               ##Starting awk code END bock here.
  for(j=1;j<=val;j++){ ##starting a for loop here from variable named j value 1 to till value of variable val here.
    print a[v[j]] FS b[v[j]] ##printing value of array a whose index is value of array v with index j, and array b with index of array v with index j here.
}}
' SUBSEP="" Input_file       ##Setting SUBSEP to NULL here and mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Comment: man. good it works. but really hard for understand =) in any case, thanks.

Comment: @Piduna, glad that it helped you, I added non-one liner form of solution too now, let me add explanation there too and let you know then.

Comment: yes, i am trying to understand you code and make it only by second column, where is ip. in any case thanks

Comment: yes i did
`awk -F"|" '!c[$2]++{val++;v[val]=$2} {a[$2]+=$1;b[$2]=$2 FS $3;} END{for(j=1;j<=val;j++){print a[v[j]] FS b[v[j]]}}' SUBSEP=""`

Comment: @Piduna, please check my edit with explanation now, let me know if All is Well with it.

Answer (score 1):

Short GNU **`datamash`** + **`awk`** solution:

```
datamash -st'|' -g2,3 sum 1 <file | awk -F'|' '{print $3,$1,$2}' OFS='|'
```

- `g2,3` - group by the 2nd and 3rd field (i.e. by *IP address* and *user id*)
- `sum 1` - sum the 1st field values within grouped records

---

The output:

```
40|192.168.1.2|user4
109|192.168.1.25|user2
118|192.168.1.3|user11
58|192.168.1.55|user3
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the sample data to include different users for ip address `192.168.1.25`:

```
$ cat ipfile
40|192.168.1.2|user4
42|192.168.1.25|user1      <=== same ip, different user
58|192.168.1.55|user3
118|192.168.1.3|user11
67|192.168.1.25|user9      <=== same ip, different user
```

And a simple `awk` script:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS="|" ; OFS="|" }
{ sum[$2]+=$1 ; if (user[$2]=="") { user[$2]=$3 } }
END { for (idx in sum) { print sum[idx],idx,user[idx] } }
' ipfile

58|192.168.1.55|user3
40|192.168.1.2|user4
118|192.168.1.3|user11
109|192.168.1.25|user1     <=== captured first user id
```

- `BEGIN { FS="|" ; OFS="|" }` : define input and output field separators; executed once at beginning
- `sum[$2]+=$1` : store/add field #1 to array (indexed by ip address == field #2); executed once for each row in data file
- `if ....` : if a user hasn't already been stored for a given ip address, then store it now; this has the effect of saving the first user id we find for a given ip address; executed once for each row in data file
- `END { for .... / print ...}` : loop through array indexes, printing our sum, ip address and (first) user id; executed once at the end

NOTE: No sorting requirement was provided in the original question; sorting could be added as needed ...

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} 
             {a[$2 FS $3]+=$1} 
       END   {for(k in a) print a[k],k}' file | sort -n

40|192.168.1.2|user4
58|192.168.1.55|user3
109|192.168.1.25|user2
118|192.168.1.3|user11
```

if user* is not part of the key and you want to capture the first value

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} 
             {c[$2]+=$1; 
              if(!($2 in u)) u[$2]=$3}     # capture first user
       END   {for(k in c) print c[k],k,u[k]}' file | sort -n
```

which ends up almost the same with @markp's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea on the same path but allows for different users:

```
awk -F'|' '{c[$2] += $1}u[$2] !~ $3{u[$2] = (u[$2]?u[$2]",":"")$3}END{for(i in c)print c[i],i,u[i]}' OFS='|' input_file
```

If multiple users they will be separated by a comma